# Why is only 1 of my ScrolledComposites scrolling with the mouse wheel?

Tags: java, swt, mousewheel, scrolledcomposite, ctabitem

Here's my current setup...  I have several tabs (Using CTabFolder and CTabItems) each with its own ScrolledComposite.  I was able get the first tab working with the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23882007/4288015 but this does not work when applied to the other ScrolledComposite on the second tab.  The second tab doesn't recognize the mouse wheel even with the MouseWheel listeners removed from both ScrolledComposites.  What might be the issue causing the first tabs ScrolledComposite to work but not the second one?

Comment: So I did a little bit of debugging and it seems that if I remove `Text theProcessAllGrainTheFinishText = new Text(grpFinish, SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.WRAP);` the scrolling works fine.  But one I add it back, it does not work...

Comment: I was able now to narrow it down to the attributes of the Text component.  It doesn't seem to like anything but SWT.NONE.  Not sure why since I have Text components in the other ScrolledComposite with SWT.READ_ONLY, SWT.WRAP, etc. and the mouse wheel scrolling works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by using StyledText instead of Text.  This allowed me to wrap the text and maintain the mouse wheel scroll capabilities.